# ifelse in abline() r

Tags: r, function, plot

I'm wondering how to get the **abline()** command in the **R code below** to draw **2 vertical** **lines** **IF tl ==2** and only **1 vertical line** **IF tl==1** with the same line color (ex. "green")?

Here is my **R Code (with no success):**

```
CBT <- function(g,r,n,tl){

curve(dt(x,n),-5,6,col="red")

abline(v=ifelse(tl==2,c(-2,2),2),col="green") ## HERE needs a fix??
}

## Test this:
CBT(.4,.05,20,2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a `if/else` condition

```
CBT <- function(g,r,n,tl){
curve(dt(x,n),-5,6,col="red")
if(tl==2){
   abline(v=c(-2,2), col="green")
  } else {
  abline(v = 2, col="green") }
}

CBT(.4,.05,20,2)
```

If we need both the condition i.e. 'tl' for 1, 2, and other cases

```
CBT <- function(g,r,n,tl){
 curve(dt(x,n),-5,6,col="red")
 if(tl==2){
  abline(v=c(-2,2), col="green")
  } else if(tl==1){
   abline(v = 2, col="green") 
 } else {abline(v=NA)}
}

CBT(.4,.05,20,2)
CBT(.4,.05,20,1)
CBT(.4,.05,20,0)
```

Comment: @parvinkarimi  I would use `if/else` condition for conditions based on a single element.  I think there is another answer which showed the `ifelse`.  If we look at the `ifelse` condition in your post, `tl==2,c(-2,2)` the logical index is of length 1 while the TRUE condition is length 2 (`c(-2,2)`) .  SO it is better to place the second in a `list`

Answer (score 2):

You can use an `ifelse` call that returns an index into a list with suitable values for your two conditions.

```
CBT <- function(g,r,n,tl){
        curve(dt(x,n),-5,6,col="red")
        abline(v= list( c(-2,2), 2) [[ ifelse(tl==2, 1, 2)]], col="green") 
  }
CBT(.4,.05,20,1.5)
```

I think the problem with trying to use `ifelse` your way is that ifelse is designed to return a value with the same length as the conditional. Using as an index lets you vary the lengths.

Comment: @42-thanks very much, it seems the same logic can't apply to `points()` command, right? For example:   `points(list(c(-2,2),2)[[ifelse(tl==2,1,2)]],-.017,bg="green",col="green",pch=21,cex=1,xpd=T)`

Comment: `points` could be accompdated but because you need to provide both an x and a y argument, you could deliver an argument list to `points` using `do.call`. Or you could have one `ifelse` for the x value and another for the y value